# Server saturation with Ajax calls

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, socket.io, zeromq

I'm using PHP over IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008.

My web application is requesting repeatedly with Ajax in the background 3 different JSON pages:

- page 1 Every 6 seconds
- page 2 Every 30 seconds
- page 3 Every 60 seconds

They retrieve data related with the current state of some tables. This way I keep the view updated.

Usually I have no much trouble with it, but lately I saw my server saturated with hundreds of unanswered requests and I believe the problem can be due to a delay in one of the request.

If page1, which is being requested every 6 seconds, needs 45 seconds to respond (due to slow database queries or whatever), then it seem to me that the requests start getting piled one after the other.
If I have multiple users connected to the web application at the same time (or with multiple tabs) things can turn bad.

Any suggestion about how to avoid this kind of problem?

I was thinking about using some thing such as [ZMQ](http://zeromq.org/) together with [Sockets.io in the client side](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client), but as the data I'm requesting doesn't get fired from any user action, I don't see how this could be triggered from the server side.

Comment: Make the request not take 45 seconds? Or don't request it every 6 seconds?

Comment: @DarkFalcon it doesn't usually take 45 seconds, but sometimes it does. I'm asking for a way to deal with this problem.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to implement it with sockets.io.. something similar is using even SO to update the question/answer votes/comments dynamically

Comment: @MateiMihai but what would trigger the message from the server side?

Comment: If the request has not come back, do not send another. But fix the serverside code and speed it up.

Comment: I think it will listen to a port.. so every message sent through that port will be catched in front end

Comment: @epascarello thanks, that sounds like some improvement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem following the recommendation of @epascarello and improving it a bit if I get no response in X time.

> If the request has not come back, do not send another. But fix the serverside code and speed it up.

Basically I did something like the following:

```
var ELAPSED_TIME_LIMIT = 5; //5 minutes
var responseAnswered = true;
var prevTime = new Date().getTime();

setInterval(function(){
    //if it was answered or more than X m inutes passed since the last call
    if(responseAnsswered &&  elapsedTime() > ELAPSED_TIME_LIMIT){
        getData()
        updateElapsedTime();
    }
}, 6000);

function getData(){
    responseAnswered = false;
    $.post("http://whatever.com/action.json", function(result){
        responseAnswered = true
    });
}

//Returns the elapsed time since the last time prevTime was update for the given element.
function elapsedTime(){
    var curTime = new Date().getTime();

    //time difference between the last scroll and the current one
    var timeDiff = curTime - prevTime;

    //time in minutes
    return (timeDiff / 1000) / 60;
}

//updates the prevTime with the current time
function updateElapsedTime(){
    prevTime = new Date().getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking about using some thing such as ZMQ together with Sockets.io in the client side...

This is almost definitely the best option for long-running requests.

> ...but as the data I'm requesting doesn't get fired from any user action, I don't see how this could be triggered from the server side.

In this case, the 'user action' in question is connecting to the socket.io server. This cut-down example is taken from one of the [socket.io getting started](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) docs:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

When the 'connection' event is fired, you could start listening for messages on your ZMQ message queue. If necessary, you could also start the long-running queries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not quite sure to understand what you said. I need to update the user view every 6 seconds right? How would the view get the update from the server side? It is the server side the one which has to make the push here.

Comment: Websockets behave differently to normal HTTP requests, in that messages can be sent in either direction, not just browser->server->browser. First, you connect to the websocket server from your browser, which fires the `connection` event. From that point, your server can send update messages directly to the browser without the browser initiating any further requests.

Comment: I know how sockets work. You are not understanding my question. This is PHP, not javascript. I can not have a single process running a setInterval function to push notifications from time to time. Something has to fire the push to the client. And that's were I'm in trouble.

Comment: Apologies, I completely failed to read the first line of the question!

Answer (score -1):

This is a very bad setup. You should always avoid polling if possible. Instead of sending request every 6 seconds from client to server, send data from server to the clients. You should check at the server side if there is any change in the data, then transfer the data to the clients using websockets. You can use nodejs at the server side to monitor any changes in the data.

Comment: I know I could use node, but the fact is that the web application is using PHP and I can not change that. Besides that, node is not perfectly integrated with Oracle DB and PLSQL procedures.